# how to hide rows with nulls in a Spotfire data table

Tags: datatable, null, spotfire

I have a data table in spotfore with columns A,B,C.
The column C has some null values. 
How can i hide these rows ?

I already tried to add a rule with column C not equal to, however i can't set null as a value.

Answer (score 2):

In the Limit Data Using Expression section, add `[C] Is Not Null`

If you're ever uncertain of the correct format for something like this, I recommend searching through the Functions in the top right of the Limit Data Using Expression window.  If you searched "null", and select the "NULL" value, it gives the following in the explanation area:

```
NULL is a keyword that can either be used to specify a null (empty) value, or, it can be a part of the 'Is Not Null' or 'Is Null' operators.

Examples:
null
[Column] Is Not Null
```

Equals/Not equals doesn't work, because a null doesn't actually "equal" anything.  This is pretty common in programming languages or GUIs, especially when they're so closely linked with SQL.

Answer (score -1):

You can explicitly filter them or replace the null values with some informative text.

Comment: Not sure why it attracted negative. I would have given specifics if asked more detailed questions maybe with a screenshot.